# Why does a Recursive CTE in Transact-SQL require a UNION ALL and not a UNION?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I get that an anchor is necessary, that makes sense.  And I know that a `UNION ALL` is needed, if your recursive CTE doesn't have one, it just doesn't work... but I can't find a good explanation of why that is the case.  All the documentation just states that you need it.

Why *can't* we use a `UNION` instead of a `UNION ALL` in a recursive query?  It seems like it would be a good idea to not include duplicates upon deeper recursion, doesn't it?  Something like that should already be working under the hood already, I would think.

Comment: Can we see some code please, because I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @Sami the definition of a recursive CTE requires an anchor query `UNION ALL`'d to a recursive query.  I am asking why it needs to be UNION ALL instead of  UNION, which I would imagine the optimizer is probably doing in some form already.

Comment: Because that is the syntax. If you have some problem with your code, with duplicated items, post it

Comment: @Ezin82 I don't have a problem with my code, and I know the syntax.  I know how to recurse in SQL.  I am asking why that mechanism is required when it seems a recursive query would want to control duplicates anyway to maintain some degree of performance, i.e. was this chosen arbitrarily, was it to try and maintain some ANSI SQL compatibility, was there a technical limitation, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume the reason is that they just haven't considered this a priority feature worth implementing. It looks like [Postgres *does* support both](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) `UNION` and `UNION ALL`.

If you have a strong case for this feature you can provide feedback at [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) (or whatever the URL of its replacement will be).

Preventing duplicates being added could be useful as a duplicate row added in a later step to a previous one will nearly always end up causing an infinite loop or exceeding the max recursion limit.

There are quite a few places in the [SQL Standards](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip) where code is used demonstrating `UNION` such as below

[image]

This article explains how [they are implemented in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/10/25/recursive-ctes/). They aren't doing anything like that "under the hood". The stack spool deletes rows as it goes so it wouldn't be possible to know if a later row is a duplicate of a deleted one. Supporting `UNION` would need a somewhat different approach.

In the meantime you can quite easily achieve the same in a multi statement TVF.

To take a silly example below ([Postgres Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/7573/0))

```
WITH R
     AS (SELECT 0 AS N
         UNION
         SELECT ( N + 1 )%10
         FROM   R)
SELECT N
FROM   R
```

Changing the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` and adding a `DISTINCT` at the end won't save you from the infinite recursion.

But you can implement this as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F ()
RETURNS @R TABLE(n INT PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON))
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @R
      VALUES      (0); --anchor

      WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @R
            SELECT ( N + 1 )%10
            FROM   @R
        END

      RETURN
  END

GO

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.F ()
```

The above uses `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` to discard duplicates. If the column list is too wide to be indexed you would need `DISTINCT` and `NOT EXISTS` instead. You'd also probably want a parameter to set the max number of recursions and avoid infinite loops.

Comment: ...so it's basically a technical limitation of SQL Server then.  Interesting!

Comment: As a side note, I really don't have a need for using a UNION, it's just struck me as counterintuitive for a long time, and yesterday I finally got curious enough to research why, only to find nobody seemed to ever discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

This is pure speculation, but I would say, that the UNION ALL ensures, that the result of each iteration can be calculated individually. Essentially it ensures, that an iteration cannot interfere with another.

A UNION would require a sort operation in the background which might modify the result of previous iterations. The program should not change the state of a previous call in the call stack, it should interact with it using input parameters and the result of the subsequent iteration (in a procedural setting). This probably should apply to set based operations, thus to SQL Server's recursive CTEs.

I might be wrong, late night brain-dumps are not 100% reliable :)

Edit (just another thought):

When a recursion starts, you have a call stack. Each level in this stack starts calculating it's result, but should wait for the result of all subsequent calls before it can finish and return it's result. UNION would try to eliminate duplication, but you don't have any records until you reach the termination condition (and the final would be built from the bottom to the top), but the result of the subsequent call is required by the ones above it. The UNION would be reduced to a DISTINCT at the very end.

Comment: Doesn't each recursion add to the stack at each call, and remove itself upon completion?  If that were the case, it would seem to me that it would dedupe as it went along.

Comment: I am not sure if that would be a the best solution performance wise. That would mean, that sorting and comparison have to happen after each iteration. I would say, that doing it after calculating the final result is more perfomant in lots of cases (surely not in all). The call stack thing in the edit is derived from the way procedural recursion works, I might be wrong when it comes to SQL Server an it's optimizer.

Comment: Doing it at the end is not the same. It can make the difference between terminating or an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

A good explanation  of [pred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3469391/pred) post speculation  here : https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html :

> Optimization note: ...... Very little memory is needed to run the above example. However, if the example had used UNION instead of UNION ALL, then SQLite would have had to keep around all previously generated content in order to check for duplicates. For this reason, programmers should strive to use UNION ALL instead of UNION when feasible.