# How to use sql recursive without union all?

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a question about sql recursive theory.
definition：if a common table expression uses itself in its definition, this is called recursion.
**`FedEmp(name, salary, manager)`**

Find all employees under the management of Hoover and whose salary is more than 100000

```
with agents(name, salary) as
    ((select name, salary                   --initial query
      from FedEmp 
      where manager = ‘Hoover’)
    union all
     (select f.name, f.salary               --recursive query
      from agents as a, FedEmp As f
      where f.manager = a.name))
select name from agents;                    --final query
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to know, is it sql recursive mush use with union all, i don't know this is the fix format or i can't use it in the other way

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Tip 2: Don't put SELECT's inside parentheses when UNION ALL.

Comment: But, I don't know how I can use outer join find all the employees which salary is more than 100000

Comment: You can use UNION as well but it won't make a difference. If you are using Oracle, you could use it's proprietary `CONNECT BY` operator instead of a common table expression

Comment: What is it you really want to know? Why are you asking whether `UNION ALL` is mandatory? What may be your problem with it? You are missing `where salary > 100000` at the end of your query, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

To have recursion you **need** `UNION ALL`, there is no other way, and it is [by definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions).

A short clarification of the mechanism behind it:

- The 1st part before `UNION ALL` serves to "get an initial set of rows".
- The 2nd part after `UNION ALL` serves to "add further rows based on what was found in the previous iteration".

The 2nd part continues being executed until at it finds no new rows to add (or until the MAXRECURSION limit is reached; which is configurable).

Also, see this related question: [Why does a Recursive CTE in Transact-SQL require a UNION ALL and not a UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47998833/1220550)

To answer the second part about finding all employees whose salary is more than 100000, I think adding `WHERE salary > 100000` at the very end would do it. The CTE finds the people recursively, without looking at salary yet; and then you filter them by salary.

Comment: "it is by definition" - you've linked documentation to SQL Server, I'm wondering if this applies to other implementations such as Postgres though ?

Comment: @baxx This should be posted as a question, not as a comment. I know nothing about PostgreSQL. The best chance of getting an answer is to post a question + add enough detail + tag it properly.