# Recursive Common Table Expressions: why use UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Recursive CTEs include an anchor query and a recursive query. The anchor selects one or more rows to begin with, and the recursive selects the rest. The rows are combined with a `UNION ALL` clause.

If the two inner queries don’t return the same rows, why do you need to combine them with a `UNION ALL` clause, and not just `UNION` ? As far as I am aware, the purpose of `UNION ALL` is to include duplicate rows.

This appears to be a requirement with Microsoft SQL, but not with PostgreSQL.

Or is there more to the picture?

Thanks to @MartinSmith’s comment, this appears to be answered in [Why does a Recursive CTE in Transact-SQL require a UNION ALL and not a UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998833/why-does-a-recursive-cte-in-transact-sql-require-a-union-all-and-not-a-union)

I’m voting to close this question.

Comment: For SQL Server it probably just doesn't allow `UNION` because this would not work well with [how they are implemented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226946/how-does-sql-recursion-actually-work/226961#226961) It processes a recursive CTE a row at a time and then goes down as far as that path takes it. Not a level at a time. You can add a `DISTINCT` or similar on to perform a distinct operation on the whole result or some other criteria but not quite the same semantics

Comment: FYI the following comment from your linked question is helpful. It also states that `UNION` is allowed in other SQL, but not in Microsoft. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226946/how-does-sql-recursion-actually-work/226961#comment447230_226961

Comment: Is this question different from this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47998833/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for your more gentle approach to flagging a duplicate. That other question does indeed answer this one. I’ll close this one.

Comment: cool, because I can't vote as dupe without instantly closing the Q I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something

Answer (score 1):

You say "just `UNION`".  In general, your thinking should be "just `UNION ALL`".

`UNION` incurs extra overhead for removing duplicate rows.  You only want to incur that overhead if you actually want to remove duplicates.  The default should always be `UNION ALL`, unless you want that extra operation.

Comment: Actually “just `UNION`”. Given that the theoretical result is supposed to be a set, and sets don’t have duplicates, this would be the expected behaviour anyway. This is why, for example you can’t `UNION` an ordered `SELECT` statement; only the result can be ordered. In any case, this doesn’t answer why `UNION ALL` is required, even when the two inner queries are disjoint.

Comment: @Manngo . . . Theory is nice.  Most people want their queries to perform optimally as well.